# Search in private, scoped NPM packages

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I'm wondering how `npm search` could search within private, scoped packages... I've tried the following:

`npm search @scopename/package-name`

but it says `No matches found for "@scopename/package-name"`. I've token and registry set in `.npmrc` properly, because I can use the packages from this scope. The registry is default (https://registry.npmjs.org/).

Any ideas why this search doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am here for the same reason

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
npm view @scope/package
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view.

I first logged in before using it, "npm login".